# How to find domain of $\sin^{-1}(xy)$?

Tags: functions

How to find domain of $\sin^{-1}(xy)$?

If we assume $xy$ to be $z$, then

$$z\ \in [-1, 1]$$

$$\implies xy \in [-1, 1]$$

after that how to do to find individual limits on $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after that how to do to find individual limits on $x$ and $y$?

You can't get individual limits because what one variable is allowed to be depends on what the other variable's value is.  This can happen with multivariable functions.  Sometimes it isn't possible to get limits for each individual variable.

You've actually already finished the problem, and you approached it correctly as well.  Anything we take the arcsine of must be in the interval $[-1,1]$.  Since we are taking the arcsine of $xy$, we will think of $xy$ as one entity, so for simplicity we can call it $z$.  Thus $z \in [-1,1]$.  Thus $xy \in [-1,1]$.  So, the *only* restriction on $x$ and $y$ is that their product $xy$ is in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Individually, $x$ can be any real number as long as $y$ is a real number such that $xy \in [-1,1]$.  Or you can "approach through $y$ first" and say $y$ can be any real number as long as $x$ is a real number such that $xy \in [-1,1]$. And the simplest way to say all this is simply $\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : xy \in [-1,1] \}$.

Comment: @Downvoter, care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The relation $|xy| \le 1$ is graphed above.

Limits on $x$ will have to depend on the value of $y$ and vice versa. The best you can do is something like $-\dfrac{1}{|y|} \le x \le \dfrac{1}{|y|}$ or 
$|x| \le \dfrac{1}{|y|}$

For example, the red line segment on the line $y=1$ show that, when $y=1$, then
$-1 \le x \le 1$

Answer (score 0):

You started well. The domain is$$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,-1\leqslant xy\leqslant1\}.$$

Comment: In addition, see http://bit.ly/2vbkTjw for a sketch to understand why there are no "individual" limits on $x$ and $y$. Because I think BKB thought the domain would be the Cartesian product of two intervals?

Answer (score 0):

You could say the domain is $-\frac{1}{|x|}\leq y\leq \frac {1} {|x|}$ along with ${x=0}$ but I'm not sure how helpful this would be for you.